# Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame

Tags: wordpress, civimember, upgrade, database, error-page

When a user tries to create a new membership from the front end we are getting this:

DB Error: already exists
Return to home page.

Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame thrown in /home1/.../public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107

When I try to create the membership manually from CiviCRM Dashboard it just churns. This was working until the latest update 4.6.8. We are running Wordpress.

Renewals seem to be unaffected for administrators and for unavailable for others.

Comment: The affected renewing members are getting

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
The page you requested is currently unavailable.
Return to home page.

When attempting to click the Renew Now button from the dashboard. The link takes them to DOMAIN/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&id=1&mid=62&reset=1

I can perform this task in the administrator account fine, and I have further tried other accounts without issue. I have checked to see if it is an account permissions issue and this problem persists even when set to full admin. I think these two may be related

Comment: Anybody? Could really use some help on this one

Comment: I have completely deleted plugin and reinstalled with no change

Answer (score 3):

I was able to narrow this down to the Member ID extension. Disabled that and the DB Error resolved it's self. ONE member is unable to renew at this time, but I can process manually